# Second monitor detected but appear to be "off"

Tags: nvidia, display, dualhead, multiple-monitors

I have been enjoying dual monitors using Xubuntu with Nvidia driver 340.58 for some time now. However, suddenly one of the monitors stops working. In nvidia-setting panel it just appears as "Off" and I couldn't change any settings.

Screenshot of nvidia-settings at https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBFCR.png

And the result of `xrandr` says DP-1 was not disconnected but has no modes.

```
xrandr: Output DP-1 is not disconnected but has no modes
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     59.9  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Any idea what might cause the problem?

Comment: **Solved by changing cable.**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is typically a connectivity issue. I experienced similar symptoms that went away after re-attaching the cable at the back of the monitor. In other cases, a new or alternative cable should be tried before anything else.